# When I delete a file from a directory I get an error which says that I cannot access my file

Tags: c#, wpf, webclient

I'm making a WPF application where I use `WebClient` to download files from a webserver. When I cancel a download in progress I want to delete the folder which contain the files I'm about to download. For the most it works as expected, but sometimes I get this error when I try to cancel a download in progress:

> Remove data error: {0}: System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access    the file 'filename.file' because it is being used by another process.
>       at System.IO.Directory.DeleteHelper(String fullPath, String userPath,  Boolean recursive, Boolean throwOnTopLevelDirectoryNotFound)
>       at System.IO.Directory.Delete(String fullPath, String userPath, Boolean recursive, Boolean checkHost)

When I click a button I first cancel the download and afterward I delete the file or files from the directory.

```
    private void cancelBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        // Get button. To read game id
        var btn = (Button)sender;

        var GameInProcess = InstallDialog.GinP.Find(item => item.downloadId == (int)btn.Tag);
        // Remove downloaded game data
        // Remove from my game lige

        //Cancel downloading
        GameInProcess.client.CancelAsync();

        Thread.Sleep(1000);

        InstallGame.removeInstallFiles((int)btn.Tag);
        MyGames.removeGame((int)btn.Tag);
        MainWindow.refreshLibrary();
        //InstallDialog.GinP.Remove(GameInProcess);
        Close();
    }
```

**removeInstallFiles function:**

```
    public static void removeInstallFiles(int gameId)
    {
        Log.Logger("Remove data");
        try
        {
            // Delete folder
            Directory.Delete(MainWindow.savePath + gameId, true);
            File.Delete(MainWindow.torrentPath + gameId + ".torrent");
            Console.WriteLine("deleted");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.Logger("Remove data error: {0}", e);
            Log.trackEvent(String.Format("Remove data error: {0}", e), "gameerror", "Game error");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are cancelling the client asynchronously, while deleting the file synchronously.   Instead of using `GameInProcess.client.CancelAsync();`, consider `GameInProcess.client.Cancel();`, if such a method exists on the client.  If not, you will need to use a Join to have your thread wait for the cancel to complete.